# Loading wsgi_mod with Apache on Windows 7

Tags: windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I have seen this question asked a number of times, and I have tried the solutions described - unfortunately the solutions have not worked for me, so I'd like to ask my own question. I hope it's not marked as a dupe or similar.

My problem is that, on Windows 7, I can't get Apache 2.0 to load the WSGI module, which I need in order to run a Django project. Let me start by describing my environment, and how I got there.

**Windows**: 
I'm on Windows 7 64-bit Enterprise with Service Pack 1.

**Python**: I have installed python 2.7.3 32-bit and put it on my path. When I type `python` in PowerShell, I see this message:

```
C:\ $ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I have installed 32-bit python, since there's no 64-bit version of the WSGI module for Windows. I have made sure to install it for all users (I have seen on other questions, that installing for all users solved the problem with loading the WSGI module, but it has not solved the issue for me). I have installed python through following steps:

1. Start PowerShell as Administrator (right click -> "run as Administrator")
2. Run the following command: `msiexec /i python-2.7.3.msi ALLUSERS=1` (as described here: http://www.python.org/getit/releases/2.4/msi/)

**Apache**: I have installed Apache 2.0 32-bit (so that the bit version of Apache matches that of Python, and that of the WSGI module). When I enter `services.msc`in the "Run" dialog (Win+r) and mark Apache, I can see the following in the description to the left:

```
Description:
Apache/2.0.64 (Win32)
```

Apache is installed in this directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2`. Before I installed mod_wsgi Apache started up just fine.

**mod_wsgi**: I have downloaded the binary for Windows and Python 2.7 from here: https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DownloadTheSoftware?tm=2 (The file is called "mod_wsgi-win32-ap22py27-3.3.so"), I have then renamed it to `mod_wsgi.so` and copied it to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Group\Apache2\modules`. Finally, I have put this line in Apache's httpd.conf: `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so`.

Now, when I try to start Apache, I'm met with this error:

```
Syntax error on line 174 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/conf/httpd.conf:
Cannot load C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Group/Apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server:
The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm pretty much stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [rubber duck](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html) helped me out tremendously here. When proofreading my question, I discovered that mod_wsgi's filename indicated that it works with Apache 2.2. I also discovered that I had installed Apache 2.0.

Upgrading to Apache 2.2 solved my problem. Hope it'll help someone out there.